# How to use www ports with several virtual hosts

Tags: freebsd, apache2

I've installed `www/wordpress` port, configured `wp-config.php` and set up Apache config accordingly. The site is running OK.

Now, what should I do if I want another site to run Wordpress? I can't set `/usr/local/www/wordpress` as root dir for another virtual host, because it would pick up config of the first one and this would be, basically, the same site.

Answer (score 0):

You install it into a different folder and create an apache virtual host.

To install wordpress:

- download it from the [wordpress website](https://wordpress.org/download/)
- create a folder for a second wordpress installation, for example /usr/local/www/wordpress2
- extract the contents of the downloaded file into that directory
- change the owner of that directory to the webserver user with `chown -R`
- create a new database for wordpress, this depends on what DB server you are using
- change the apache configuration like so:

  # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
      ServerName www.example.com
      ServerAlias example.com 
      DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/wordpress"

  ServerName other.example.com
      DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/wordpress2"

Clients send the hostname in the HTTP GET, so the webserver can direct them to different websites based on that option.

For more information see the Apache Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Finally, run the setup script from your browser.

Comment: The problem is that I install wordpress using FreeBSD packages (`pkg`). I don't see a way to set custom directory for installation.

Comment: I edited it to add a short description on how to install WP manually

Comment: Ok, so the answer is to install it manually? You could've say just this.